# Correlate events with extrinsics in a utility.batch call in Polkadot

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

In Polkadot and Kusama blockchains emitted module events has the phase property so we can correlate them with the extrinsic that triggered that event but I can't do the same when the extrinsic is included in a `utility.batch` (https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#batchcalls-veccall) or `utility.batchAll` (https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#batchallcalls-veccall) extrinsic as far as I know.

Is there a way to correlate an event with the related extrinsic included in a `utility.batch` or `utility.batchAll` call?

Comment: Hey, would you be so kind as to repost this great question on https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ -- and @NukeManDan over there?
Very happy to assist on our shiny new Substrate (and friends) home for your questions!

Comment: Sure! See https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/174/correlate-events-with-extrinsics-in-a-utility-batch-call-in-polkadot